# how to ignore @rest directives from apollo codegen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I'm using `@rest` directive to request some data from REST API, but when I use the command `apollo client:codegen` this thrown an error like so:

```sh
 Cannot query field "acceptanceToken" on type "Query"
```

This error points to this `@rest` query.

### Query that thrown the error

```js
export const wompiAcceptanceTokenQuery = gql`
  query WompiAcceptanceToken {
    acceptanceToken
      @rest(
        type: "WompiAcceptanceToken"
        path: "some/api/endpoint"
      ) {
      data
    }
  }
`
```

There is a way to ignore this directives from npm `client:codegen` script?

### Current NPM script

```sh
"typegenerate": "apollo client:codegen --target=typescript types --globalTypesFile=src/types/globalTypes.ts && rm -rf types",
```